# C# Как конвертировать string в int[,]

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется переменная content, в которой хранится string строка:

```
 15 14 13 12 11 13 14 15
 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26
 25 24 23 22 21 23 24 25
```

Нужно конвертировать её в 2D массив типа int. Но я даже не знаю как это можно реализовать

```
void загрузитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] loadmap = new int[8,8];
            string path = @"C:\Users\lxve_every1\Desktop\ser\loadmap.txt";

            var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8);

            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(content);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    loadmap[i, j] = content; // Наверное, нужно сначала конвертировать content в int, а затем сделать из него 2D массив?
                    Console.WriteLine(loadmap[i, j]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(map);
            map = loadmap;
    }
```

Comment: `Split` по переводу строки и перебрать, а потом `Split` по пробелам и тоже перебрать. Наверное даже можно в один `Linq` запрос всё собрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читать файл можно построчно или сразу в массив строк.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
int[,] map = new int[8, 8];
for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    string[] tokens = lines[i].Split();
    for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        map[i, j] = int.Parse(tokens[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно надо использовать TryParse

Comment: @Виктор здесь причин упасть гораздо больше, чем просто встретить не число